# Type checking with react v15.5. React.PropTypes is deprecated

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

When I go to React documentation page I see that now there is no guide about typechecking with PropTypes. Then I open guide about [react context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and I see message that states I should now use [prop-types library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types). But this library has no documentation. I would like to know how to use it with React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question is kind of off-topic for Stack Overflow, it give me a heads-up for this change, so thanks :) I found an article explaining the change [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-react.proptypes). Quoting:

> [...] instead of accessing PropTypes from the main React object, install the prop-types package and import them from there:
>
> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import PropTypes from 'prop-types';      //// CHANGE (1) HERE
>
> class Component extends React.Component {
>   [...]
> }
> Component.propTypes = {
>   text: PropTypes.string.isRequired      //// CHANGE (2) HERE
> }
> ```

Comment: ups, haven't looked in blog section.

Comment: should I npm-install this package so its listed in package.json dependencies or just use it without it (because its one of react dependencies)???

Comment: I believe you have to include it in `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the size of React's core, prop types have been moved out into their own package ([prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)).

The new prop-types module works in exactly the same way as the original React one, except now you'll access the `PropTypes` object by importing it, rather than as a property of React.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

myComponent.propTypes = {
  foo: PropTypes.string
};

// rather than

myComponent.propTypes = {
  foo: React.PropTypes.string
};
```

This deprecation warning only landed in React v15.5, which was released yesterday. I imagine the documentation will stabilise before too long.

For now, the current documentation is still fine, as long as you follow the rule above.